# LUIS service created through AZURE CLI not showing up on the LUIS Portal

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding

I have created a `LUIS service` using `AZURE CLI` using an email id which is the owner of the subscription. When I open `luis.ai` I cant see the LUIS app list, though I also have all the permissions of the specific resource group also I can see the `LUIS service` in Azure Portal when logged from my email.

Also, I have checked the `LUIS Service` is hosted in WEST US and I am opening the corresponding `LUIS` website.

Comment: Can you give the commands used to create and publish to LUIS? Try to be so complete as you can with everything you have done.

Comment: And try to ask a question. Like "I have done this and this" (with used commands) "What have I done wrong to achieve this"

Comment: Could you post how you got this issue resolved.I am facing similar issue, but I created my luis app in azure portal using Ansible roles.My luis app is showing up in azure portal, but not in luis portal.